# Create custom url which executes code (not render render a Wordpress entity)?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I am looking to be able to create a url, which when matched will execute some PHP code and output the result. Can this be done?

I'm familiar with `rewrite_rules_array`, which lets you create custom url structures and map them to an custom post types, taxonomies, etc. I am hoping to avoid having to have a blank/placeholder page cluttering up Wordpress to direct to.

I thought about using the `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` actions, but this only works with Ajax requests and I'd like to be able to hit them with a standard request.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: hey Louis, you can target `wp_ajax` endpoints with standard requests, so I'd suggest to go that route,, or if you like you can choose newer standars REST method `register_rest_route`

Comment: @KresimirPendic `wp_ajax` calls have urls like http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=do_something_cool, was hoping for just a top level page name.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a rewrite rule, you just need to exit execution before the main query is run.

First, add a query var that will get set by the rewrite rule:

```
function wpd_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'my_var';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpd_query_vars' );
```

Next, the rewrite rule:

```
function wpd_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^my-url/?$',
        'index.php?my_var=true',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_rewrite_rule' );
```

Lastly, we hook `parse_request` and check for our custom var, run our code, and exit:

```
function wpd_parse_request( &$wp ){
    if ( array_key_exists( 'my_var', $wp->query_vars ) ){
        echo 'do something';
        exit;
    }
    return;
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_parse_request' );
```